# Search Button with loading animation inside button

Tags: html, button, bootstrap-4

I have a Search button and I tried to get loading animation inside the search button but no idea how to do it. Please help me with your suggestions.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary tap" type="button" id="searchForContent">Search</button>

<div class="container"> 
     <div id="searchedContent"></div>                     
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const button = document.getElementById("searchForContent");
const searchedContent = document.getElementById("searchedContent");


function search() {
  button.innerHTML = "Searching.... ";
  // you can change this if you calling any api or something
  setTimeout(() => {
  button.innerHTML = "Search";
  searchedContent.innerHTML = "Search results are: "
  }, 3000)
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary tap" type="button" id="searchForContent" onclick="search()">Search</button>

<div class="container"> 
     <div id="searchedContent"></div>                     
</div>
```